# Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm hitting an error when trying to restore a tensorflow model after the training has completed. In particular, I have a GAN and I separately save generator and discriminator weights to be restored later on. I do like this:

Save model weights for generator and discriminator CNNs (both are classes inheriting from `tf.keras.Model`):

```py
g_ckp_dir = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'generator')
d_ckp_dir = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'discriminator')
generator.save_weights(os.path.join(g_ckp_dir, 'checkpoint'))
discriminator.save_weights(os.path.join(f"{d_ckp_dir}", 'checkpoint'))
```

Then, I load as:

```py
g_ckp_dir = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'generator')
d_ckp_dir = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'discriminator')
generator.load_weights(os.path.join(g_ckp_dir, 'checkpoint'))
discriminator.load_weights(os.path.join(f"{d_ckp_dir}", 'checkpoint'))
```

However, the model does not seem to be restored correctly because predictions are not meaningful, and I get also the warnings below:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Detecting that an object or model or
> tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values. See the
> following logs for the specific values in question. To silence these
> warnings, use `status.expect_partial()`. See
> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restorefor
> details about the status object returned by the restore function.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).to_image_ops.4.kernel
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).to_image_ops.4.bias
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).to_image_ops.5.kernel
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).to_image_ops.5.bias
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).to_image_ops.6.kernel
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).to_image_ops.6.bias
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).spade_blocks.0.conv1.kernel
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).spade_blocks.0.conv1.bias
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).spade_blocks.0.conv2.kernel
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).spade_blocks.0.conv2.bias
> WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the
> restored object: (root).spade_blocks.1.conv1.kernel
> ...

What is wrong with this? Why do I get such an error?

I use **Python 3.8.10**, **TensorFlow 2.9.1**, and **Keras 2.9.0**

Comment: It probably has to do with how you implement the `generator` and `discriminator`, which prevents the model weights from properly saving. Can you post the code of where you define the `generator`
?

Comment: Hi @FrederikBode, thanks for your help. This is a customized model which unfortunately I cannot share. Are there any recommendations on this? why do you think the problem is in the model implementation? Is there a trick I can use to verify the model implementation is fine for keras before trying to reload the model?

Comment: No idea that's why I wanted to take a look. For debugging, I would start with logging the names of the variables and in the checkpoint and see if they match using `model.trainable_variables` (for the model) and ```reader = tf.train.load_checkpoint('./tf_ckpts/')
shape_from_key = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
dtype_from_key = reader.get_variable_to_dtype_map()
``` for the checkpoint file

Comment: I'm getting same WARNING in VSCode notebook when using `keras_tuner` API. `tuner = kt.RandomSearch(...)`.

Comment: @Edison did you understand what is the problem?